# Is it possible to get place boundaries coordinates from the auto-marked boundaries on Google Map?

Tags: maps, google-api-php-client

I'm looking to get the place/location boundaries without manually marking them. Google already marks a place boundary as shown on the attached image. Is there a possibility to get the boundary coordinates as drawn or to automatically draw a boundary of a place/location.

[image]

I'm stuck so far on the way forward on this.